# What are the meanings of the columns of the symbol table displayed by readelf?

Tags: symbols, elf

Could someone explain the columns shown of the symbol table using `readelf`?

Answer (score 78):

Consider the following:

Symbol table `.symtab` contains 1203 entries:

```
 Num:    Value  Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
 310: a0008120     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  ABS _gp  
 734: a0000010    32 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT   77 v 
 818: 9d000018   496 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   71 main 
 849: a0000124     4 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT   78 phrase 
 955: a0000000     9 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT   77 peppers  
1020: a000023c   192 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT   80 bins
```

- `Num:` = The symbol number
- `Value` = The address of the Symbol
- `Size` = The size of the symbol
- `Type` = symbol type:  `Func` = Function, `Object`, `File` (source file name), `Section` = memory section, `Notype` = untyped absolute symbol or undefined
- `Bind` = `GLOBAL` binding means the symbol is visible outside the file. `LOCAL` binding is visible only in the file. `WEAK` is like global, the symbol can be overridden.
- `Vis` = Symbols can be default, protected, hidden or internal.
- `Ndx` = The section number the symbol is in.  ABS means absolute:  not adjusted to any section address's relocation
- `Name` = symbol name

Comment: what does "UNIQUE" means as a value for bind??

Comment: @Caladain What does 'The size of the symbol' mean? Say, if the symbol is a function name, dose 'Size' mean the size of the function(e.g. how many instructions this function has)?

Comment: Not how many instructions, but rather how many bytes (generally, may vary by target). For example, in some asm output from gcc, I see the following code at the end of the function `_main`: `.size _main, .-_main`. This directive tells **as** that the size of the function `_main` is the current location minus its start address.

Answer (score 0):

I think Ndx field shows the section number where that symbol is defined.

Do a `readelf -a <file>`, and find out which section the address corresponds to for a given symbol.

I bet the section number of that section will appear in Ndx field.

Answer (score -2):

Ok this question is old, but good old Google yields it if you are looking for readelf symboltable and NDX;

Here is what I found out:

The C code compiled with avr-gcc:

```
int XYZ = 123;
int ABC;
```

when the generated elf file is analyzed using

```
readelf --symbols KoreOS.elf
```

you get as output:

```
Num:    Value  Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
...
148: 0080200b     2 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT    2 XYZ
...
258: 00803878     2 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT    3 ABC
...
```

I use the NDX column as hint if the variable is initialized or not. But I found no documentation anywhere so I'm just guessing.

greetings,
Dominik

Comment: in objdump's manpage `or *UND* if the section is referenced in the file being dumped, but not defined there.`. so i assume readelf's UND is also a imported but undefined symbol. still curious about which document define this.

Comment: NDX is the section number. The initialized global symbols are usually stored in ".data" section. Uninitialized global symbols or zero initialized are stored in ".bss" section. The NDX column of the globals in this example has the numbers of these sections as they appear in the section headers list as output by readelf. Do not ever imply any specific number, but rather correlate it to the section name.

Comment: NDX = "UND" is often used with WEAK symbols. A weakly declared symbol does not need a definition. And a symbol without a definition is not placed in any section, so it is marked as "UND". Weak symbols with non-zero value are marked with NDX = ABS (absolute value). E.g. 245: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  WEAK   DEFAULT  UND ___deregister_frame_info

Answer (score -3):

You can either:

```
man readelf
```

or look at these tutorials:

- [The ELF Object File Format by Dissection](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/1060)
- <strike>Understanding ELF using readelf and objdump.</strike> (Edit: link removed; linuxforums.org has been hacked)

Comment: I am also interested in an answer to this question.  In particular, what is Ndx (from readelf -s)?  Probably it is obvious to someone who understands elf.  I looked at both the man page and the documents you listed and could not find the information there.  Maybe I just missed it?  It would not be the first time.

Comment: Above all: read the standards pointed to by the LSB: http://www.sco.com/developers/gabi/2003-12-17/contents.html being the most interesting.