# How to set the The section number of a symbol when compiling ELF binary?

Tags: c, linux, assembly, linker, elf

The test is on 32-bit Linux, x86.

Suppose in my assembly program `final.s`, I have to load some library symbols, say, `stdin@@GLIBC_2.0`, and I want to load these symbols in a fixed address.

So following instructions in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28355292/how-to-load-library-defined-symbols-to-a-specified-location), I did this:

```
echo ""stdin@@GLIBC_2.0" = 0x080a7390;" > symbolfile
echo ""stdin@GLIBC_2.0 (4)" = 0x080a7390;" >> symbolfile
gcc -Wl,--just-symbols=symbolfile  final.s -g
```

And when I checked the output of symbol table, I got this:

```
readelf -s a.out | grep stdin
53: 080a7390     4 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT  ABS stdin@@GLIBC_2.0
17166: 080a7390     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  ABS stdin@GLIBC_2.0 (4)
```

And comparing to a common ELF biary that requires `stdin` symbol:

```
readelf -s hello.out | grep stdin

17199: 0838b8c4     4 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT   25 stdin@@GLIBC_2.0
52: 0838b8c4     4 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT   25 stdin@GLIBC_2.0 (4)
```

So an obvious difference I found is that the `Ndx` column, say, the section number of my fixed position symbols are `ABS`. Please check the references [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3065535/what-are-the-meanings-of-the-columns-displayed-by-readelf).

When executing the `a.out`, it throws a `segmentation fault` error.

So my question is, how to set the section number of the symbol fixed position?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to load these symbols in a fixed address.

You are *importing* these symbols from GLIBC. Unless you are doing a fully-static linking, you get *no say* in what address these symbols end up at.

> So my question is, how to set the section number of the symbol

That question makes no sense: section number itself is *meaningless* and `25` may refer to `.bss` in one executable, but to `.text` in another.

Your section `25` just happens to be `.bss` *on this particular system* and for this particular build. Try building a fully-static binary, and you are likely to see section `24` instead.

Anyway, a normal executable gets `stdin` copied from `libc.so.6`. You will do well to read [this description](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/08/25/load-time-relocation-of-shared-libraries) of the process, and pay special attention to "Extra credit #2: Referencing shared library data from the executable" section.

But it may be easier to understand the fully-static case first.

Comment: Hi, yes, I do want to load/import these symbols into `.bss` section. Is there any chance that I can make it?